# Methods deriving values or additional attributes?

Tags: c++, oop

Let's say I have a class `A` with a data member `info` which is of user-defined `enum` type.
`info` lets me deduce a lot of information that I need when using class `A`, by using a `switch` on `info`. For example, I may want to get a `string` version of `info`, a more general `short_info` (several `info` values being grouped under the same `short_info` value), etc.

Here are the 2 approaches I can imagine, with what I understand of their respective advantages and disadvantages:

1. Create methods in `A` that do a `switch` on `info`
   Advantage: less data members in `A`, therefore less storage space
   Disadvantage: the methods have to be called each time for values that don't change between calls, possibly resulting in slower execution
2. Create data members initialized at construction time and updated if `info` changes
   Advantage: faster access to values, no need for additional computation each time a geter is called
   Disadvantage: more storage space

Is one of these 2 approaches usually better ? Does it depend on whether the `info` data member can be modified after initialization, or some other factor ?
Or is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is one of these 2 approaches usually better ?

Not really. They both seem somewhat bad.

> Or is there a better way of doing this ?

Yes. Have the type of `info` be a class with that data as members.

e.g. instead of

```
enum Info {
    info1,
    info2
};

class A {
    Info info;
    string info_desc() const; // switch on info
    ShortInfo info_abbr() const; // another switch
};
```

You instead have

```
class Info {
    string desc;
    ShortInfo abbr;
}

Info info1 { "first info", ShortInfo::first };
Info info2 { "second info", ShortInfo::other };

class A {
    Info info;
}; // Does this do anything anymore?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this indeed looks much nicer.
What if the `Info` is a library `enum`, meaning you cannot declare it as a class since its possible values are fixed ?

Comment: You can declare an parallel `Info` in a different namespace, with a `library::Info` member